# webpart to show related tasks

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In my main list dispform I've added a webpart (List view webpart) using SPD.

- I want to display all tasks (from task list) that relates to my main
  list item.
- In the task list I can see related items column, this contains the
  main list item name.

I cant figure out how to use filters (in SPD) to display only item related tasks. Is their a correlating field between tasks list and main list ? Any ideas how this is possible ?

Comment: This is a good question and without opening designer myself I couldn't tell you. However I do strongly recommend that if you want an answer, that you should look at a your previous questions and accept them, this will make people more inclined to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

As always there a couple of ways to do this...using the list you create view which has the filter in place (within Sharepoint itself).  Or you could create your own webpart in VS which references the list and you can filter on a query within the code.